# Zoom in to display portion of a window captured by Process

Tags: c#, process, window

I am trying to use capture the process of another concurrent application and display it in a panel in my own WinForm. The code I use:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] myProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("the_external_program_i_want");
    Process p = myProc[0];
    IntPtr appWin = p.MainWindowHandle;
    SetParent(appWin, this.Handle);
    SetWindowLong(appWin, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
    MoveWindow(appWin, panel1.Location.X, panel1.Location.Y, panel1.Width, panel1.Height, true);
}
```

However, what the code does is that it will capture the entire window of the external process. What I would like to achieve is to "crop" this window; to display only a particular region of the window of the external process.

How should I go about doing this best?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the Form the parent, make the Panel the parent:

```
        SetParent(appWin, panel1.Handle);
        SetWindowLong(appWin, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
        MoveWindow(appWin, -100, -100, panel1.Width+100, panel1.Height+100, true);
```

Note that I moved the app to (-100, -100).  This means the top left corner of the app will be shifted 100 pixels to the left and up from the top left corner of the panel (but out of sight because the panel will **clip** it).  I adjusted the width/height by however much the window was shifted so that it will extend to the bottom right of the panel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However this seems to crop from the top left corner only. Is there a way to specify the bottom right boundary as well?

Comment: You'd have to calculate the correct negative offset for the left corner coupled with an appropriate size of the panel to achieve cropping on all sides.

Comment: For my application, it seems that instead of cropping to the exact boundary as specified by 1) the negative offset, and 2) the panel size, what my program does is that it tries to "compress" the entire window (minus off the top-left offset) to fit exactly into the panel.

So even if I were to edit the panel, the program will just compress the views accordingly.

Comment: Edit: To add on, my best guess is that there is a movable bar (not sure if it is classified as a child dialog) within this region that might interfere with the code.

Comment: In that case set the size of the panel to achieve the cropping but don't resize the target window. Use SetWindowPos() with SWP_NOSIZE instead of MoveWindow().